# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Multiple Regex on a property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

I would like to know if a way exists in asp.net mvc 2, to have multiple regular expression on a proprety. For example :

```
[RegularExpression("[^0-9]", ErrorMessageResourceName = ValidationMessageResourceNames.OnlyDigits, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
[RegularExpression("[^<>]{2,}", ErrorMessageResourceName = ValidationMessageResourceNames.SpecialCharErrorCreateAccount, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
public string City { get; set; }
```

The target here, is two have two specific error messages, one for the digits and one other for the special Chars and the fact that the min lenght must be 2 chars.

Thanks in advance for the help, or experience.

Etienne.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements exactly. What are the rules for a string to fail/pass validation? Could you show some examples of string you do or don't want to match?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
    public class DigitsAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public DigitsAttribute()
            : base("[^0-9]")
        {
        }    
    }

    public class SpecialCharsAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public SpecialCharsAttribute()
            : base("[^<>]{2,}")
        {
        }
    }
```

Use:

```
[Digits]
[SpecialChars]
public string City { get; set; }
```

Comment: can u plz have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567194/custom-model-validation-is-not-firing-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: Will this use client validation out-of-the-box or not? EDIT: Now I see that it doesn't.. :(

Answer (score 1):

### Change attribute usage with a custom class

The best solution is of course to create a custom attribute that inherits from `RegularExpressionAttribute` but sets different attribute usage settings. The main setting is `AllowMultiple` that you need to set to `true`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class MultiRegularExpressionAttribute: RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    ...
}
```

You would use this attribute just like you use the existing `RegularExpressionAttribute`, but you'd have the ability to put multiple of them on the same property.

Comment: Can you show what exactly goes into the class? I really wanted to use this method but I am fairly new to this. The isValid method in the new class somehow never got visit and I have no idea why.

Comment: Do not use this solution,see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652533/should-i-use-multiple-regularexpression-attributes/35658502#35658502

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
[RegularExpression("[^0-9]|[^<>]{2,}", ErrorMessageResourceName = ValidationMessageResourceNames.OnlyDigits, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
public string City { get; set; }
```

Here '|' has been used as OR condition to match

Comment: I'm interested in the downvote. This _should_ be the way it works, though I'm having some trouble with .net Core…