# ASP.NET MVC - Multiple Regex on a property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My problem with MVC validation is that I have a lot of different condition where different message needs to be shown and there isn't enough default attribute type for me to put all those message in. I am aware that I could create custom attribute to solve this problem, but then I realize a lot of the validation I want could be done with simple regex checking, so instead of creating multiple different classes I tried to find a way to have multiple regexp attribute on a property.

After some research I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803437/asp-net-mvc-2-multiple-regex-on-a-property/24330090#24330090) which suggest simply to inherit the RegularExpressionAttribute class, which is EXACTLY what I want, but I couldn't do the actual implementation myself as I am fairly new to .NET.

Here's the suggested code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class MultiRegularExpressionAttribute: RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    ...
}
```

can anyone help me fill the actual content of the class out? I tried to fiddle around and it ran without error, but the isValid method never got visited and I am so very lost.

Comment: What do you mean _have more error message variety_? You can only display one message.

Comment: I have a lot of different condition where different message needs to be shown and there isn't enough attribute type for me to put all those message in, that's what i meant.

Comment: You cannot apply `AllowMultiple=true` to a validation attribute if your expecting to use client side validation.